# The difference with sup and without sup

Tags: calculus

#### The difference with sup and without sup，how to judge and choose the use

---

For example, here is rudin's "Root" Test:

Given $\sum a_n$, put $\color{Green}{\{\alpha =\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup \sqrt[n]{\left|a_n\right|}\}}$

Here is [mathworld "Root" Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RootTest.html)

[image]

I also see [SupremumLimit](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SupremumLimit.html)

So, as title shows, and the question may not only occurs in this example.

Others maybe RatioTest, ... other Tests, the use of Sup and Inf and without use, when should I use, and when should I not use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking: the texts that use limsup instead of lim are just being more careful.  You can certainly prove that *if* $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}u_k^{1/k}$ exists, and call its value $\rho$, then the root test applies: if $\rho>1$ you get divergence, whereas you get absolute convergence for $\rho<1$.

However, the result given by Rudin is stronger!  Whenever the limit exists, necessarily the limsup also exists and gives the same values; but, there are certainly sequences which do not have a limit but which still have a limit supremum.

Comment: Hi, [the supremum limit (also called the limit superior or upper limit)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SupremumLimit.html)

are they the same [UpperLimit](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UpperLimit.html)?

Comment: No, they aren't.  Take the sequences $a_1=1$, $a_n=0$ for $n\geq 2$. The limsup is 0; but, if I understand the definition of the "upper limit" correctly (by the way, something I haven't seen in 10 years of formal mathematics education), the upper limit would be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Rudin's statement is more general and doesn't require you to prove the existence of a limit. This is because the limsup of a (real) sequence is *always* defined as an extended real number (*i.e.*, as either a real number or $\pm \infty$), while not all sequences have limits. So Rudin's version of the root test doesn't make any assumptions about the sequence $\{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\}$, and hence it can be applied to any series $\sum a_n$. In contrast, to apply the version of the root test using $\lim \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$, you first need to prove that this limit exists.

It's also worth noting that $\lim \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ whenever $\lim \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ exists, and so there is no real benefit to using the $\lim \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ version of the root test. (Of course, analogous statements can be made about the ratio test, too.)